# How to get equal parts of multiple strings/array?

Tags: php, arrays, string, compare

I have the following point: a xls file contains one column with codes. The codes have a prefix and a unique code like this:

```
- VIP-AX757
- VIP-QBHE6
- CODE-IUEF7
- CODE-QDGF3
- VIP-KJQFB
- ...
```

How can I get equal parts of strings or an array? perfect would be if I get an array like this:

```
- $result[VIP] = 3;
- $result[CODE] = 2;
```

An array with the found prefix and the sum of cells with that prefix. But the result is not so important at the moment.

I couldn't find a soloution how to get equal parts of two strings: how to compare this `"VIP-AX757"` and `"VIP-QBHE6"` and get a result that says: `"VIP-"` is the same prefix/part in this two strings?

Hope someone has an idea.
thx!

Comment: So what is your code?

Answer (score 1):

-drum roll- Time for a one-liner!

```
$result = array_count_values(array_map(function($v) {list($a) = explode("-",$v); return $a;},$input));
```

(Assumes `$input` is your array of codes)

If you are using PHP 5.4 or newer (you should be), then:

```
$result = array_count_values(array_map(function($v) {return explode("-",$v)[0];},$input));
```

Tested in PHP CLI:

[image: screenshot of result]

Comment: Thanks. Actually I am using a similar function - but: the "-" in "VIP-" was just an example. The Codes could also be: "VIP##AX757" and "VIP##QBHE6" than the prefix would be "VIP##".

Comment: You can adjust the `function() { .. }` part to do anything you want, whatever it needs to do to get the prefix.

Comment: exatly that what I am searching for: a way to find the prefix if I dont't know a delimiter.

Comment: Kinda tough when you've got nothing to go on. If you can define *some* kind of rule, such as "the prefix has letters followed by symbols", then you might have something to work with.

Comment: wanted a autofunction for that. only thing would be to compare subtr for subtr, maybe char for char to find equal parts - but that would melt the server away.. ;) the can have up to 200.000 entries. so: no fast php funtcion to do that? I found "similar_text()" but its only calculating the similar parts - if it would return "this is the similar part: xxxx". thx anyway!

Answer (score 0):

If the prefix is always followed by a '-' then you can do something like this:-

```
foreach ($codes as $code) {
    $tmp = explode("-",$code);
    $result[$tmp[0]] += 1;
}
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the variability of the data, but something like:

```
preg_match_all('/^([^-]+)/m', $string, $matches);
$result = array_count_values($matches[1]);

print_r($result);
```

If you don't know that there is an `-` after the prefix but the prefix is always letters then:

```
preg_match_all('/^([A-Z]+)/im', $string, $matches);
$result = array_count_values($matches[1]);
```

Otherwise you'll have to define exactly what the prefix can contain if it's not the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Since you stated via comment to Niet that you don't have a reliable delimiter, then we can only write a pattern that identifies your targeted substrings based on their location in each line.

I recommend `preg_match_all()` with no capture group, a start of the line anchor, and a multi-line pattern modifier (`m`).

I've written a `preg_split()` alternative, but the pattern is a little "clunkier" because of the way I'm handling the line returns.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ja87J))

```
$string = 'VIP-AX757
VIP-QBHE6
CODE-IUEF7
CODE-QDGF3
VIP-KJQFB';

var_export(array_count_values(preg_match_all('~^[A-Z]+~m', $string, $out) ? $out[0] : []));
echo "\n\n";
var_export(array_count_values(preg_split('~[^A-Z][^\r\n]+\R?~', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)));
```

Output:

```
array (
  'VIP' => 3,
  'CODE' => 2,
)

array (
  'VIP' => 3,
  'CODE' => 2,
)
```